# WPF DataGrid with DataTable: Create ComboBox with default value

Tags: wpf, datagrid, default

I have a `DataGrid` which uses a `DataTable` as its data source.

Let's say I create my DataTable with the following columns:

```
MyDataTable.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("ColumnSample", System.Type.GetType("System.Double")));
MyDataTable.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("ColumnMode", System.Type.GetType("MyProject.ViewModels.ModeEnum")));
MyDataTable.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("ColumnValue", System.Type.GetType("System.Double")));
```

And now I create a row:

```
row["ColumnSample"] = SampleCount;
row["ColumnMode"] = ModeEnum.PEDAL;
row["ColumnValue"] = val;
```

As you can see, the column "ColumnMode" is being populated with an **enum**.
How can I get the DataGrid to **preselect** a value from the enum when this cell is created?
In my case, the DataGrid shows an *empty* cell until I click it. Then it displays a dropdown with my enum values.

Comment: I also can't get this to work I'm afraid - it looks like the column with the enumeration doesn't update its display text when the enumeration value is altered from code. The whole behaviour is a bit odd really because the documentation http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datacolumn.datatype(v=vs.100).aspx doesn't mention using enum as a datatype at all.

Comment: You're right, it doesn't. Apparently it can handle collection and the like flawlessly, though.

Comment: I'm still looking for an answer to this problem.